# Autorest.exe 0.7.3 is for 64-bit only?

Tags: nuget, autorest

I'm trying to setup a project which contains a package called Autorest. This was installed via NuGet and inside the packages folder of the project is an executable tool Autorest.exe. Unfortunetly, this version is for 64-bit and I can't run the tool to get my API from my web service. What can i do?

Comment: Does your project actually use AutoRest when it's running? AutoRest is a tool to generate code from OpenAPI specs (aka Swagger) If your service doesn't run AutoRest, then just remove it.

Comment: My service doesn't use autorest, but my client project does. The  nuget package include that tool but it doesn't run in 32-bit Windows. I had to downgrade package to 0.16.0